# C when should char** be null terminated?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, printf

Couldn't find any questions on StackOverflow that addresses this question.

I realize that char* arrays don't have to be NULL terminated, but was wondering when you would want it to be?

For example, when debugging my code, I use a lot of printf() to see if my variable is correct at certain stage of the code.

I have an char** values that holds 4 char*, I made the last char* NULL.
With NULL terminating, printfs from values[0] to values[3] give me this
*note: names is just another array that I print right after I finish printing the values array*

```
Testing values1[0]: %HOME/bin:%PATH
Testing values1[1]: /%HOME/include
Testing values1[2]: /%HOME/lib
Testing values1[3]: (null)
Testing names2[0]: PATH
Testing names2[1]: IDIR
Testing names2[2]: LIBDIR
```

I have an char** with 3 char*, all of which are valid char*.
Without NULL terminating, printf from values[0] to values[3] gives me this (names doesn't show)

```
Testing values1[0]: %HOME/bin:%PATH
Testing values1[1]: /%HOME/include
Testing values1[2]: /%HOME/lib
```

I think when printf(...., values[3]) would be an undefined behavior, such as printing a garbage value, but as shown in the output above, everything including and after printf(...., values[3]) seems to not have been executed.

Comment: `NULL` and `null` are different...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite catching it.
I did values[3] = NULL;
What is this difference between NULL and null?

Comment: `values[3] = NULL` is valid, but then, `printf("%s", values[3])` is not...

Comment: But why did I get "Testing values1[3]: (null)?" as an result of the printf("%s", values[3])?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What does the loop for printing the values look like? It makes sense to have a `NULL` pointer as sentlnel value for an array of pointers, but your program must also make use of that value somehow.

Comment: @MOehm 
Hi! So I didn't actually use a for loop, because I was testing this specific case
I did:

'printf("Testing values[0]: %s\n": values[0]);'
printf("Testing values[1]: %s\n": values[1]);
printf("Testing values[2]: %s\n": values[2]);
printf("Testing values[3]: %s\n": values[3]);
printf("Testing names[0]: %s\n": names[0]);
printf("Testing names[1]: %s\n": names[1]);
printf("Testing names[2]: %s\n": names[2]); `

Comment: The answer is: any time you use the character array as a `string` (e.g. passing it to a function that expects a *nul-terminated* string), the array must be *nul-terminated* or undefined behavior will result as what ever function you pass the array to happily reads past the end of your array looking for the *nul-terminating* character.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi David, yes I understand character array/char[] and char* and their behavior with regards to null-terminated.
My question is more specifically aimed at an array of char* (an array of character arrays). This question came to me while I'm implementing my own unique string parser for an systems programming assignment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion here. First of all:

- NULL refers to a null pointer constant which you only use for setting a pointer to point at "nothing", an invalid memory location.
- Null termination, sometimes spelled "nul" to not confuse it with the above, means putting a zero character `'\0'` (sometimes called "nul character") at the end of a character array to state where your string ends. It has nothing to do with NULL pointers what so ever. A better name than "null termination" might be *zero termination*, as that is less confusing.

Now as it happens, 0, NULL and `'\0'` all give the value zero, so they could in practice be used for the wrong purpose and the code will still work. What you should do, however, is this:

- Use `0` for integers.
- Use `NULL` for pointers.
- Use `'\0'` to terminate a characer array and thereby making it a C string.

---

Next matter of confusion:

> I have an char** values that holds 4 char*

Pointers do not hold values. Arrays hold values. Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers. Pointer-to-pointer is not an array, nor is it a 2D array.

Though in some circumstances, you can get a pointer to the first element from an array.

An array of pointers to strings of variable length can be declared as: `char* string_array [N];`. You could iterate through this array by using a pointer-to-pointer, but that's not a good idea. A better idea is to use array indexing: `string_array[i]`.

Overall, there exists very few cases where you actually need to use a pointer-to-pointer. Returning a pointer to an allocated resource through a function parameter is the normal use for them. If you find yourself using pointer-to-pointers elsewhere, it is almost a certain indication of bad program design.

For example, one particular case of very wide-spread but 100% incorrect use of pointer-to-pointer is when allocating 2D arrays dynamically on the heap.

---

> when should char** be null terminated?

Never. That doesn't make any sense, as explained above. Your should most likely not use `char**` to begin with.

You could however end a character pointer array with NULL, to indicate the end of the array. This is common practice, but don't confuse this with zero termination of strings.

Example:

```
const char* str_array [] =
{
  "hello",
  "world",
  NULL
};

for(size_t i = 0; str_array[i] != NULL; i++)
{
  puts(str_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. It helped cleared up a lot of misunderstanding for me.
    I just have one question regarding char*[]  and char**.
    Say I have an char** output, I know the size of output, let's say I have a for loop through output, using i as the index. I understand that output[i] is the equivalent of saying *(output+1). But why is it that I'm able to do this output[i] = NULL even though output is a char**? I remember something about pointer decaying into arrays (or was it the opposite way around) but I'm not sure if that has something to do with it

Comment: Btw, I meant (asterisk)(output+1), but comment formatting is foreign to me, so the asterisk(referencing) was interpreted as a mini-Markdown :(

Comment: @JJGong It is pointer arithmetic. If you have a `char** output` pointing at the first item of an array of character pointers, then `output[i]` will give you pointer number `i` in that array of pointers. Just as `int* output = int_array; ... output[i]` will give you integer number `i` in an array of integers.

Comment: mmm, I understand. I guess what am I really curious about is under what circumstance would you use a array of character pointers vs a , double char pointer. I feel like they function almost the same way except the double char pointer doesn't have a "size" unless you have another variable to keep track of the size, while an array of character pointers have a fixed size when you initialize it. But it looks like you can do pointer arithmetic and deferencing by index on both types.

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer from my TA, as a response to "when should char** be null terminated?" which I find reasonable. It would be cool if there are other reasons to why you would do this.

"This is a good conceptual question, and you can think of it as analogous to why C strings are null-terminated.

Suppose you didn't want to explicitly store the length of an array (because it's extra data for you to manage and pass around, etc). How would you know where the array ends? The NULL at the end acts as a sentinel value so you can simply iterate over it until you reach the magic end-of-array value.

If you have a fixed array size or are storing it in some other way, the NULL end isn't necessary."

Comment: Agree with this - good response from your TA.  My view on this is that `NULL` termination and maintaining a count are both valid ways of ensuring you don't go out of bounds and invoke undefined behavior.  They both have their place, and knowing which one to use in a given situation is the mark of a good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

As per `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()`, `%s` conversion specifier

> `s` If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.

So, you may not pass a `NULL` as the argument. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You cannot predict the behaviour of UB.

What you can do is, put a check on the argument to be `!= NULL` and then, pass the variable. Something like

```
 if (values[n])
   puts(values[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each string needs to be null terminated. Easy option would be to memset the full array with null (i.e. 0 or '\0').

Alternatively, if you don't want to null terminate, then you need to keep track of the length of the string.

Comment: `NULL` is not the _same_ as `'\0'`.

Comment: I understand that strings (char*) need t be null terminated.
But under what circumstance would you do so, for an array of strings (char** or char*[]).

Answer (score 0):

In C99 (& POSIX), the only array of `char*` which is *required* to be `NULL` terminated is the `argv` second argument to `main`. Hence your `main` function is (or should be) declared as

```
int main(int argc, char**argv);
```

and (at least on POSIX systems) it is required (and enforced by the runtime [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)) and you should expect that:

- `argc` is positive
- `argv` is an array of `argc+1` pointers, each of them being a C string (so ending with a `\0` byte)
- its last element `argv[argc]` is required to be the `NULL` *pointer*
- two different pointers in `argv` (i.e. `argv[`*i*`]` and `argv[`*j*`]` with both *i* and *j* being non-negative and less than `argc+1`) are not [pointer aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) (that is the same pointer value)

Of course, some libraries may also have functions whose argument might have similar requirements. That should be documented.